# How to add rule under content

Tags: table-of-contents, rules

I would add a rule under `CONTENTS` like this:

[image]

How can I  do? I have to use some particular package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code may suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Contents}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\medskip\hrule\medskip}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]